# Link to individual Org-mode tag from headline

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, hyperlinks

I frequently want to follow an individual tag on a headline to see all the other headlines with that tag, however currently the entire tag block is bound as an agenda link, not each tag.

I've read up a bit on making custom links in Org but it seems like changing the behavior of the tag links will require [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) or replacing whatever function handles the linking.

Does anyone have a starting point in the Org source for this?

Comment: It looks like the solution will involve modifying the regexp used by `org-activate-tags`, but the function will likely need to be revised to loop through all the tags in a given line -- i.e., the function presently examines the line as a whole.  Other areas relating to fontification that rely upon `org-activate-tags` may also need to be modified similarly to accommodate the loop approach.  I won't have time, however, to work on this project; but, perhaps this comment is sufficient to steer someone in the right direction.